# How to find unix/linux sytem info using java or shell script?

Tags: java, linux, unix, sh, system-information

How to find unix/linux system info like OS version, RAM, no. of processors, hard disk, memory dedicated to a particular process, memory utilization of java using java or shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the version of the kernel, use `uname -r` in a shell script. All kinds of information regarding the hardware can be retrieved from the files in `/proc`.

`/proc/cpuinfo` contains information about the CPU's, including their number. `/proc/meminfo` shows the total physical memory, free memory, etc.

If you only want to fetch a particular field, you can filter the output like this:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
```

`df` shows you all of the mounted storage devices and their used space.

`/proc/PID/status` shows the amount of virtual memory dedicated to the process, where `PID` is the numeric process id.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [sysinfo.sh](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/17005.html) for a starter - it's easy to extend with your own modules.